# interface bound ipv6 address is learnt as loopback address in conf.routes6 in scapy

Tags: python-2.7, ipv6, scapy

I simply want to send an ipv6 icmp echo request and print the reply. I tried the following

```
import logging, sys
from scapy.all import *
pkt=IPv6(dst="4000::7", src="4000::6") / ICMPv6EchoRequest()
reply=sr1(pkt)
reply.show()
```

When I send the packet I got the following response but didn't get any icmp response

```
- WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination 4000::7 (no default route?)
```

Then I did a packet-sniff to see why i got no answer. I checked all my available interfaces and found out that the packet was not send.
so after a while i found out that the routing table that scapy uses thinks that 4000::6 is a loopback address instead of being applied on an interface. however, the routing table of linux clearly says it's configured on eth1. also, a "ping6 4000::6" works fine.

Please suggest me how to fix this

Comment: By the way, those addresses, `4000::6 and `4000::7`, are not valid IPv6 addresses. Your OS may know this.

Comment: Try to use valid IPv6 addresses.

Comment: I tried with the ipv6 address 2001::6 and it worked. Thanks!!